# display image on window with Applet

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, applet, processing

I am doing a basic exercise on Java with the PApplet class defined in the processing package.
I am running on OS X Yosemite with Eclipse on a 2011 MacBook pro[image]. My JDK is up to date.

Basically I want to load and display a resized image on a given window and draw something over it.

The code is the following

```
package tests;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class MyApplet extends PApplet{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
PImage img;

public void setup(){
    size(400, 400); // set size of the window       
    stroke(0); //set pen color
    img = loadImage("http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~minnes/palmTrees.jpg", "jpg");
    img.resize(0, height);
    //System.out.println(height);
    image(img, 0, 0);

}

public void draw() {
    int[] color = sunColorSec(second());
    fill(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
    ellipse(width/4, height/5, width/4, height/5);
}

public int[] sunColorSec(float seconds){

    int[] rgb = new int[3];
    float diffFrom30 = Math.abs(30 - seconds);
    float ratio = diffFrom30/30;
    rgb[0] = (int) (255*ratio);
    rgb[1] = (int) (255*ratio);
    rgb[2] = 0;
    return rgb;
}
```

}

The problem is the following: if I comment the line `size(400, 400)` in the setup() method everything is quite ok.
When I uncomment it I get the following result (see the picture attached): the image that I loaded is not resized and it is shown on a small part of the window located in the left low corner, plus it is upside-down.

I don't understand if it is a problem of the code or an OS-X problem: can someone help me please?

Comment: This works fine for me using Windows 10 and Processing 3.

Comment: thanks, at least I know it is not a  programming error...I did not mention about processing but I installed it recently so it should be up to date but I will check.

Answer (score 0):

For Processing 3.x in Eclipse, your sketch should follow this pattern (notice that size() now goes in settings):

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Template extends PApplet {

    PImage img;

    public void settings() {
        size(512, 200);
    }

    public void setup() {

    }

    public void draw() {

        background(0, 30, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PApplet.main(new String[] { Template.class.getName() });
    }
}
```